# Using >> without explicitly declaring it in a monad

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to get good at Monads and have written the following Monads and functions in which I use the `>>` (in the `apply`-function) although it is not declared in the Monad itself. How come this is possible to compile, as I understand http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#walk-the-line it is required to declare it in the  instantiation of the Monad as is the case with the `Maybe Monad`.

```
data Value =
    NoneVal
  | TrueVal | FalseVal
  | IntVal Int
  | StringVal String
  | ListVal [Value]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data RunErr = EBadV VName | EBadF FName | EBadA String
  deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype CMonad a = CMonad {runCMonad :: Env -> (Either RunErr a, [String]) }

instance Monad CMonad where
  return a = CMonad (\_ -> (Right a, []))
  m >>= f = CMonad (\env ->  case runCMonad m env of                   
          (Left a, strLst) -> (Left a, strLst)
          (Right a, strLst) -> let (a', strLst') = runCMonad (f a) env in (a', strLst ++ strLst')) 

output :: String -> CMonad ()
output s = CMonad(\env -> (Right (),  [] ++ [s]))

apply :: FName -> [Value] -> CMonad Value
apply "print" [] = output "" >> return NoneVal
```

Furthermore, how would I make it possible to show the output (print it) from the console when running apply. Currently I get the following error message, although my types have `derive Show`:

```
<interactive>:77:1: error:
* No instance for (Show (CMonad Value)) arising from a use of `print'
* In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: For the last question, you're not deriving any instances for `CMonad`, which is where the error is coming from. GHC can't derive those instances for a function type anyway; they don't make a lot of sense to ask for. Finally, that definition of `>>=` at the very least has a typo in it - make sure you check that it obeys the laws.

Comment: @Carl , I suspect you are hinting at `(a', strLst' ++ strLst)` where you would expect `(a', strLst ++ strLst')` instead.

Comment: your definition of `>>=` doesn't use `m` at all, which is definitely incomplete at best.

Comment: @Carl , now it should be fixed. Missed part of my code that must have been leftout when I copied it into the browser. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `>>` operator is optional, not required. The [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) states that the *minimal complete definition* is `>>=`. While you *can* implement both `>>` and `return`, you don't have to. If you don't supply them, Haskell can use default implementations that are derived from either `>>` and/or `Applicative`'s `pure`.

The type class definition is (current GHC source code, reduced to essentials):

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
    (>>=)       :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

    (>>)        :: forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b
    m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k
  
    return      :: a -> m a
    return      = pure
```

Notice that `>>=` lacks an implementation, which means that you *must* supply it. The two other functions have a default implementation, but you can 'override' them if you want to.

If you want to see output from GHCi, the type must be a `Show` instance. If the type wraps a function, there's no clear way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `Monad` in the standard Prelude is as follows: (simplified from [the Prelude source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#local-6989586621679571642))

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
    (>>=) :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

    (>>) :: forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b
    m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k
    {-# INLINE (>>) #-}

    return      :: a -> m a
    return      = pure
```

It's a typeclass with three methods, `(>>=)`, `(>>)` and `return`.

Of those three, two have a *default implementation* - the function is implemented in the typeclass, and one does not.

`Monad` is a subclass of `Applicative`, and `return` is the same as `pure` - it is included in the `Monad` typeclass (or at all) for historical reasons.

Of the remaining two, `(>>=)` is all that is needed to define a `Monad` in Haskell. `(>>)` could be defined outside of the typeclass, like this:

```
(>>) :: (Monad m) => forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b
m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k
```

The reason this is included is in case a monad author wants to override the default implementation with an implementation which is more efficient.

A typeclass method which is not required is know as *optional*.

Haddock documentation automatically generates a 'Mnimal complete definition' based on the methods without default implementations. You can see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad:%7E:text=satisfy%20these%20laws.-,Minimal%20complete%20definition,-(%3E%3E%3D)) that the minimal definition of `Monad` is indeed `(>>=)`.

Sometimes, all methods can have default implementations, but they are not optional. This can happen when one of two methods must be provided, and the other is defined in terms of it. This is the case for the [`Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Traversable) typeclass, where `traverse` and `sequenceA` are both implemented in terms of each other. Not implementing either method will cause them to go into an infinite loop.

To let you mark this, GHC provides the [`MINIMAL`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html#minimal-pragma) pragma, which generates the neccesary compiler warnings, and ensures the Haddocks are correct.

As an aside, failing to implement a required typeclass method is by default a compiler warning, not an error, and will cause a runtime exception if called. There is no good reason for this behaviour.

You can change this default using the `-Werror=missing-methods` GHC flag.

Happy Haskelling!